# Assigning signed short to unsigned short without typecasting

Tags: c, integer

I'm just curious about following three assignments.

1. `signed short` is directly assigned `unsigned short`?

   ```
   signed short tS16_var = -3000;
   unsigned short tU16_var = tS16_var;
   ```
2. `signed short` is assigned to `unsigned short` after typecasting?

   ```
   signed short tS16_var = -3000;
   unsigned short tU16_var = (unsigned short) tS16_var;
   ```
3. `signed short` is assigned to `unsigned short` after `signed short` typecasting?

   ```
   signed short tS16_var = -3000;
   unsigned short tU16_var = (signed short) tS16_var;
   ```

Which one is a best practice? All three cases outputs same value without any warning.

Comment: The casts are completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 4):

All three cases give the same result.

During an assignment, the value on the right side is converted to the type of the object on the left side.  For integer types, this conversion is implicit and does not require a cast.

In the first case, the conversion happens implicitly as part of the semantics of the `=` operator.  In the second case, the conversion happens as a result of the explicit cast, and the result of that cast (which has the same type as the left side of the assignment) is assigned directly.  In the third case, the cast does nothing because the operand of the cast is the same type specified in the cast, so this case is equivalent to the first case.

For all three cases, a `signed short` is converted to an `unsigned short`. The rules for this conversion are specified in section 6.3.1.3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> *1* When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than `_Bool`, if the value can be represented by the new
> type, it is unchanged.
>
> *2* Otherwise,  if  the  new  type  is  unsigned,  the  value  is  converted  by  repeatedly  adding  or subtracting  one  more  than
> the  maximum  value  that  can  be  represented  in  the  new type
> until the value is in the range of the new type.
>
> *3* Otherwise,  the  new  type  is  signed  and  the  value  cannot  be  represented  in  it;  either  the result is implementation-defined
> or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

In this case, paragraph 2 applies because the value is out of range for an unsigned type.  Assuming a `short` is 16 bit, one more than the maximum value is 65536 so the result of the conversion is 65536 - 3000 = 62536.

You don't show how you're printing the result, but if you print with the `%u` format specifier this is the value that will be printed.